# Datalist acting weird

Tags: html, cross-browser, html-datalist

I'm using a datalist to populate a live search box. The box searches on cities from a database and the datalist should be populated with a maximum of 10 suggestions which changes when the user types.

However, the suggestions that show does not entirely correspond with the option items in the datalist, I'm only able to see a few of them. For example, say that I would search for New York City. The first suggestion does not appear until I've completed typing "New " and cities I see are "New Glasgow" and "New Westminster", when looking at the source code I can see that the datalist is indeed populated with 10 cities that starts with "New ".

```
<input type="text" list="searchResults">
<datalist id="searchResults">
  <option value="New Glasgow"></option>
  <option value="New Westminster"></option>
  <option value="New Milton"></option>
  <option value="New Malden"></option>
  <option value="New Amsterdam"></option>
  <option value="New Delhi"></option>
  <option value="New Kingston"></option>
  <option value="New Yekepa"></option>
  <option value="New Plymouth"></option>
  <option value="New Corella"></option>
</datalist>
```

"New Y" gives me "New Yekepa" while the datalist is populated with "New Yekepa", "West New York", "East New York" and "New York City". "New Yo" all the way to "New York" only gives me "New York City" but of course East and West are still there in the source code.

This is in Chrome. When I tried it in Firefox it worked slightly better, showing more results - sometimes all 10 but more often only 7-8 of the 10 that I could see where present in the datalist.

Comment: works for me with FF18 and Chrome23!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uU5ZW/, have you tried it isolated? maybe some other code in your page is messing it up.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm constantly updating the content of the datalist with Ajax. I found [this](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/6/14/Example-of-a-dynamic-HTML5-datalist-control) tutorial which seems to achieve what I want and I will try it as soon as I get back home.